# glfwGetGLVersion() returns 2.1 on OS X Lion

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, osx-lion, glfw

I'm trying to set up an OpenGL 3.2 context on Lion. I've got this code to set up the window:

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

if (!glfwOpenWindow(640, 480, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    return -1;

glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

// Get OpenGL details
int major, minor, rev;
glfwGetGLVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
std::cout << "GL Version: " << major << "." << minor << "." << rev << std::endl;
```

The GL version comes out as 2.1, even though I'm running OS X Lion and an AMD Radeon 6750M which apparently supports 3.2. Also, I ran this bit of C code [here](http://forum.jogamp.org/OpenGL-3-2-in-OS-X-10-7-td3186330.html) which returned 3.2. I'm using GLFW 2.7.8. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: `GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE` Please stop doing that.

Comment: Does the PC you run this on have an integrated GPU as well as the dedicated one? If it does you might need to explicity tell the AMD driver to use your main card.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why should he not set GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT to GL_TRUE?

Comment: @FullFrontalNudity - yeah there's an Intel HD3000 as well. How would I tell it to use the 6750M?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to call `glfwInit()` before the calls to `glfwOpenWindowHint`:

```
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

if (!glfwOpenWindow(500, 500, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    return -1;
```